Error: Conflicting values set for option Trusted regarding source
I have to install dbeaver in Ubuntu, so I'm trying to run this command:
sudo apt update && sudo apt install dbeaver-ce

but I am getting this error:
E: Conflicting values set for option Trusted regarding source http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic
E: The list of sources could not be read.

I tried with
deb [trusted=yes] http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic restricted main

but I am getting this error
Command 'deb' not found, did you mean:
  command 'den' from snap den (1.2.0-0)
  command 'dub' from snap dub (1.19.0)
  command 'edb' from deb edb-debugger (1.3.0-1)
  command 'debi' from deb devscripts (2.22.1ubuntu1)
  command 'dcb' from deb iproute2 (5.15.0-1ubuntu2)
  command 'dub' from deb dub (1.27.0-2)
  command 'dab' from deb bsdgames (2.17-29)
  command 'dex' from deb dex (0.9.0-1)
  command 'debc' from deb devscripts (2.22.1ubuntu1)
  command 'deb3' from deb quilt (0.66-2.1)
  command 'derb' from deb icu-devtools (70.1-2)
See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.


Does this answer your question? How to solve "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source..." for a deb repository?

@kos i updated my question according by your suggestion

Please post the full content of /etc/apt/sources.list
